# Joining two tables unsure of join to use

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get data from two SQL tables but I am unsure of what join to use and the same tables have the same `customers_id` table would I use an inner join?

```
table - customers

customers_id
customers_firstname
customers_lastname
customers_email_address

table - orders


customers_id
customers_street_address
customers_suburb
customers_city
customers_postcode
customers_state
customers_country
```

Comment: What information are you trying to retrieve from the database?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what type of database is this?

Comment: Not familiar with that one.  When I googled "OSC Database" I found a bunch of stuff about OSCommerce.  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Yep don't use it if you want a good cart use OpenCart its more up to date.

Comment: lol, I'll remember that.  Going to add the MySQL tag to your question.  From what I've read OSCommerce runs on tom of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what results you want.  If you want every record in Customers regardless of whether there is a matching record in orders the you would use an `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  If not you would use an `INNER JOIN`.  [This is the article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) I typically refer people to for a basic explanation of joins.

An `INNER JOIN` would look like this:

```
SELECT c.customers_id, 
       c.customers_firstname, 
       c.customers_lastname, 
       o.customers_street_address,
       o.customers_city,
       o.customers_postcode,
       o.customers_state
FROM customers as c
INNER JOIN orders as o
ON c.customers_id = o.customers_id
```

I purposely did not do `select *`.  Try to get into the habit of only selecting the columns you want from tables instead of everything.

Comment: The article you linked to shows pictures of set operations, not relational joins. For example, the first picture is `A INTERSECT B`, the second is `A UNION B`, the third is `A`, etc.

Comment: @onedaywhen, did you read the article or just look at the pictures?  While you could get the same visual representations for a join and an intersect the article is clearly talking about joins...

Comment: I've read the article. I understand that the first picture is supposed to be a visual representation of the SQL query `SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB`. But if you taught someone to visualise an `INNER JOIN` this way, how would you get them to visualise the SQL `TABLE A INTERSECT TABLE B`?

Comment: I wouldn't use a visual example to try and explain the difference between a join and an intersect.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN Ya you can use it.

You can write below query to get your all data from two tables.I am going to write full join query for you.y

```
select customers.customers_firstname,
       customers.customer_lastname,
       orders.customers_city 
from customers 
INNER JOIN orders 
  ON customer.customers_id = orders.customers_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The join you should use depends on which information you are trying to retain, based on the customer ID. If you're looking to retain all of the information from `customers` even if there is no match with `orders` you would use a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). Conversely, if you wanted to retain all the information from `orders` even if there were no match with `customers` you would use a [right join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp).

If you want to return all of the information, and combine rows which have a match, use a [full join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp). Finally, you can use an [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) if you *only* want the rows which have a match from either table.

Answer (score 0):

> the same tables have the same `customers_id` table

I think you meant to say they have a common column, being `customers_id`, in which case you can use `NATURAL JOIN`.